# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults synchronize gives wrong result objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

I want to save high score using 
`synchronize`
 in my app,but i get gibberish number. Here what i got :
**GameScene.m**

```
    if (highScore <score) {
    highScore = score;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:highScore forKey:@"highScore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
  }
```

**GameOver.m**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *rezult =[prefs stringForKey:@"highScore"];

    SKLabelNode *highscorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Menlo-Bold"];
    highscorelabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)rezult];
        highscorelabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 280);
        highscorelabel.fontSize = 45;
        highscorelabel.zPosition = 5;
    [self addChild:highscorelabel];
```

Why I'm getting wrong value and how to fix this problem?

Comment: `[prefs setInteger:highScore forKey:@"highScore"];` you write an integer; then you read it back as pointer to a string: `NSString *rezult =[prefs stringForKey:@"highScore"];` – of course it will be never the same; you are lucky it has not crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a wrong value because `rezult` is a `NSString`, you should change this:

```
NSString *rezult =[prefs stringForKey:@"highScore"];
```

to this:

```
NSInteger rezult = [prefs integerForKey:@"highScore"];
```

Answer (score -1):

try to don't init another nsuserdefaults every time just use 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:surname.text forKey:@"Nume"]; to write 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Name"] to read

AND MAKE SURE YOU USE THE SAME OBJECT TYPE!